# How to get Spark to raise an exception when casting a DataFrame to a Dataset with a case class that has fewer fields?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have a DataFrame `df` with row type `(col1: Int, col2: String)`. If I have a case class `MyClass(col1: Int`) (missing `col2: String`), then `df.as[MyClass]` will not raise an exception.

How could I get it to raise an exception so I know that my case class is missing some fields compared to the DataFrame?

###### Edit

Adding a bit more info. My main use case is to fail if upstream data sources change their schemas. It works fine if `df`'s schema has fewer columns; `MyClass2(col1: Int, col2: String, col3: Double` => `df.as[MyClass2]` fails with the following exception.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `col3` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`col1`, `col2`].
```

Comment: Why do you want to check schema class instead of data? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @mrsrinivas Mostly schema evolutions. For example, if upstream data sources add columns, I want the pipelines to fail at this very first read stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.as[]` method has some [documentation in the source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/87a5442f7ed96b11051d8a9333476d080054e5a0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L451-L461) (I'm linking to v3.4.0, the latest as of the date of this post). The important bit is this:

> If the schema of the Dataset does not match the desired `U` type, you can use `select` along with `alias` or `as` to rearrange or rename as required.
>
> Note that `as[]` only changes the view of the data that is passed into typed operations, such as `map()`, and does not eagerly project away any columns that are not present in the specified class.

This means that the behaviour you are seeing is completely expected. Since `.as[]` does not eagerly project away any columns that are not present in your `MyClass` class, you'll have to do it yourself using `.select`.

So to answer your question: through only using the `.as[]` method, you can't get these errors to take place.

Please note that you're still able to use typed operations on those columns that you did specify in your schema. Consider the following example:

```scala
scala> val df = Seq((1, 2), (3, 4)).toDF("col1", "col2")
scala> case class MyClass(col1: Int)

scala> df.show
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|   2|
|   3|   4|
+----+----+


scala> df.as[MyClass].map(_.col1 + 1).show
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    2|
|    4|
+-----+
```

If you really want to trigger an error, you could do so by manually comparing the schemas. A very simplified example:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

val classSchema = Encoders.product[MyClass].schema
val dfSchema = df.schema

if (classSchema != dfSchema)
  throw new RuntimeException("Your schemas are not the same")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to register (*inject*) a resolution rule using [SparkSessionExtensions.injectResolutionRule](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSessionExtensions.html) that would extend (*improve*) how Analyzer works.

It's said that after analysis a query is going to produce some result. You have to stop it and that's where resolution rules come in.

---

Thinking about it a little more, such infrastructure not-really-application-specific features should not be handled by user code (written by a developer) but the Spark SQL "platform" itself that can and should be extended.